# Powershell object where the expanded properties become just properties

Tags: powershell

I collect two files that both contain an equal number of strings and am trying to join them into 1 object with each being a named propery.

```
$Users = Get-content C:\temp\Users.txt
$Languages = Get-content C:\temp\Languages.txt
```

Using the code below:

```
$myHashtable = @{
    Name     = $user
    Language = $Languages
}
$myObject = [pscustomobject]$myHashtable
```

The $myObject looks like

```
Name                        Language                                  
---------                -------------                                  
{Todd, Sara, Mike...} {English, Spanish, French...}
```

Can I adjust my code in so $MyObject outputs the following?

```
Name                        Language                                  
---------                ------------- 
Todd                       English
Sara                       Spanish
Mike                       French
```

Comment: If your existing `MyObject` was created with the code snippet you included, then `$Name` and `$Language` were both string *arrays* when it was cfreated. Are they coming to you as arrays? It looks like you want a array of *un-named* custom objects (usually created in a loop), like the output of `Import-Csv`. Can you edit your question to show how your data is acquired?

Comment: @Keith Miller I have corrected the verbiage for more clarity. There really is no other way at this point to collect the data any other way, I am going to expirement with turning both text files to a single csv with each datas occupying adjacent columns and then import it using the command you reccomended. Thats a fantastic idea thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your additional information, you could use:

```
$Users     = Get-content C:\temp\Users.txt
$Languages = Get-content C:\temp\Languages.txt

$MyObjects = $Users | ForEach-Object -Begin {$i=0} -Process {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Name'     = $Users[$i]
        'Language' = $Languages[$i++]
    }
} -End {}
```

This is fine for working with the whole collecdtion. If you wanted random access to individual elements, a hashtable keyed on 'Name' might be a better idea:

```
$Users     = Get-content C:\temp\Users.txt
$Languages = Get-content C:\temp\Languages.txt

$MyObjectHashTable = $Users | ForEach-Object -Begin { $hash=@{} ; $i=0 } -Process {
    $hash.Add( $Users[$i] , $Languages[$i++] )
} -End { $hash }
```